# Can you lock a VM in Virtual box to avoid accidental deletion?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

How do I lock my Virtual Machines (VM) in virtual box to avoid accidental deletion? IE: Password? Prompt?

Comment: This belongs to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you can download the extension pack, which allows you to set a password from the vbox downloads page, but I don't know whether or not this would make you enter the password before deleting it. To do so, download the extension pack from vbox downloads page, open up vbox, highlight the machine in question, go to settings, general, encryption(tab above name). There, enable encryption (checkbox), whichever encryption you prefer, password (anything you want).